# JavaScript for-loop alternative: repeat(n, function(i) { ... });

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

This is the regular for-loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) { ... }
```

It is used to iterate over arrays, but also to just repeat some process `n` times.

I use the above mentioned form, but it repulses me. The header `var i = 0; i < n; i++` is plain ugly and has to be rewritten literally every time it is used.

I am writing this question because I came up with an alternative:

```
repeat(n, function(i) { ... });
```

Here we use the `repeat` function which takes two arguments:
1. the number of iterations,
2. a function which body represents the process that is being repeated.

The "code-behind" would be like so:

```
function repeat(n, f) {
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        f(i);
    }
}
```

(I am aware of the performance implications of having two additional "levels" in the scope chain of the process)

BTW, for those of you who use the jQuery library, the above mentioned functionality can be achieved out-of-the-box via the `$.each` method like so:

```
$.each(Array(n), function(i) { ... });
```

---

So what do you think? Is this `repeat` function a valid alternative to the native for loop? What are the down-sides of this alternative (other than performance - I know about that)?

Native:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Alternative:

```
repeat(10, function(i) {
    // do stuff
});
```

Comment: whatever floats your boat man...maybe it's because I've been coding for like 25 years but IMO the for(..) syntax as-is works just fine for me (and the syntax is pretty much the same for many other languages' for loops)

Comment: One nice advantage is that the `i` variable doesn't clutter up your scope. Apart from that I'd have to say *Meh*. :)

Comment: I like the idea : _code your intention, not what the machine will be doing to achieve it._

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it's an interesting thought, but if you dislike the syntax for the loop, you could always do a different type of loop:

```
var i = arr.length; 
while (i--) {
    // do stuff
}
```

the reverse while loop is generally faster than a for loop as well.

Comment: Hm, this reverse while loop definitively looks better. :)

Comment: .. especially if it's written in one line: `var i = n; while (i--) {`. I might start using this ...

Comment: That's pretty neat. Might take a second for another coder to understand when they first see it, but seems pretty elegant.

Answer (score 10):

You say you want a revolution... Well, you know: ruby did it just before (?)

```
Number.prototype.times = function(func) { 
    for(var i = 0; i < Number(this); i++) {
        func(i); 
    }
}
```

means

```
(50).times(function(i) {
    console.log(i)
})
```

Anyway, don't fight against C, you'll always lose :-P

Answer (score 2):

To address the issue of not having the break statement as others have mentioned, I would solve it this way:

```
function repeat(n, f) {
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (f(i) === false) return;
    }
}
```

Then returning `false` from within a loop handler will be equivalent to `break`.

Another disadvantage is that the context changes. You may want to add the option of proxying a context into the loop handlers:

```
function repeat(context, n, f) {
    if (!f) f = n, f = context, context = window;

    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (f.call(context, i) === false) return;
    }
}
```

Now, an **advantage** is that the index is preserved by the function scope, to avoid a common bug:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        alert(i); // Will alert "10" every time
    }, 1000);
}

repeat(10, function (i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert(i); // Will alert "0", "1", "2", ...
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: you could save up some bytes there `if(f(i)===false)return;`

Comment: sometimes it's a feature, not a bug. Suppose you want to find a value, or add it at the bottom if it doesn't show up.

Comment: Oh, also, as somebody mentioned below: `return` doesn't work properly, but I think, using this code, you could pretty much return whatever the call returns, or break if it's `false`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems pretty valid. I honestly don't think that performance would decrease too much. But there is however one big downside, that is easily fixable: the **break** statement.

```
function repeat(n, f) {
   for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      var tcall=i;
      tcall.die=function(){i=n}
      f.call(tcall);
   }
}
```

This way you would be able to call `this.die()` instead of `break;` which I think would throw an error.

Comment: I like the `.die` idea, although pass it in as a separate argument. You'll find that the `die` property is immediately lost after assigning it to a primitive.

Answer (score 1):

Besides what you have already stated the main downside I see is that a "return" statement will work differently. (Which is often why I end up using "for" over "$.each" many times in my own ventures.)