# How to repeat execution in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Basically, I want to repeat the console.log for `5 times` I use [repeating - npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/repeating)
This might sound very basic but I can't figure out how to use this to simply repeat the `console.log('test');` for 5 times using `nodejs` I need this for a node application that should repeat a special code multiple times in `nodejs`. Hope someone here might know a solution to it.

> app.js

```
const repeating = require("repeating");

repeating(5, console.log('test'));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript for-loop alternative: repeat(n, function(i) { ... });](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929113/javascript-for-loop-alternative-repeatn-functioni)

Comment: your approach will not repeat the call of `console.log`, calling it at once and once as you might have noticed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `repeating` to print repeating strings:

```js
const repeating = require('repeating');

console.log(repeating(100, 'unicorn '));
```

Check [DOCS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/repeating).
`repeating(count, [string])` function only takes a string.

---

For calling a function multiple times, you could use a for loop.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  console.log("Hi");
}
```

The code above would be like below in one line for loop

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) console.log("Hi");
```

You can have recursion.

```js
(function repeat(number) {
  console.log("Hi");
  if (number > 1) repeat(number - 1);
})(5);
```

There are more examples in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17624356).